# Understanding Debt Deflation

Tags: macroeconomics, finance, financial-economics, debt

I read the following explanation for debt deflation in my textbook:

> To better understand how this decline in net worth occurs, consider what happens if a firm in 2018 has assets of 100 million (in 2018 dollars) and 90 million of
> long-term liabilities, so that it has 10 million in net worth (the difference between
> the value of assets and liabilities). If the price level falls by 10% in 2019, the real
> value of the liabilities would rise to 99 million in 2018 dollars, while the real value
> of the assets would likely remain unchanged at 100 million. The result would be
> that real net worth in 2018 dollars would fall from 10 million to 1 million (100
> million minus $99 million)

I don't get how the fall in prices raises the real value of liabilities from 90 to 99 instead of 100 dollars because 90/price level = 90/(1-0.10) = 100. Could anyone clarify?

Answer (score 2):

Liabilities in 2018: \$90 million
Liabilities in 2019: \$90 million

Price level falls 10% from 2018 to 2019, implies 1 2019 dollar is worth 1.1 2018 dollars.
"exchange rate": 1.1 2018D/2019D

\$90 million 2019D * \$1.1 2018D/2019D = \$99 million 2018D

Answer (score 2):

As [pointed out by James Wattam](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/50003/1601), it is possible to interpret

> price level falls 10% in 2019

as
$$
\frac{P_{2018}}{P_{2019}} = 100\% + 10\%.
$$

I agree with you that the interpretation
$$
\frac{P_{2019}}{P_{2018}} = 100\%-10\%
$$
makes more sense. The question comes down to what the writer of the text considers the base year.